# Modifying the url parameter to download images from multiple web-sites

Tags: python, web-scraping

I was trying to download images from all the cases included in CaseIDs array, but it doesn't work. I want code to run for all cases.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as rq
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from tqdm import tqdm

CaseIDs = [100237, 99817, 100271]

with rq.session() as s:
    for caseid in tqdm(CaseIDs):
        url = 'https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-CIREN/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID= {caseid}'
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

        url = urljoin(url, soup.find('a', text='Text and Images Only')['href'])
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

        links = [urljoin(url, i['src']) for i in soup.select('img[src^="GetBinary.aspx"]')]

        count = 0
        for link in links:
            content = s.get(link).content
            with open("test_image" + str(count) + ".jpg", 'wb') as f:
                f.write(content)
            count += 1
```

Comment: Both answers should solve the main problem, but I think there is one more thing: `count` is set to zero for every `caseid` item, so the images of the second `caseid` would overwrite the images of the first, etc. If that is a problem, you can solve it if you move the declaration `count = 0` before the first for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use `format()` like this:

```py
url = 'https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-CIREN/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID={}'.format(caseid)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an f-string to pass your `caseId` value in, as you're trying to do:

```py
url = f'https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-CIREN/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID= {caseid}'
```

(You probably also need to remove the space between the `=` and the `{`)